# How to collect failed keys when Postgres csv copy throws foreign key constraint error

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

In trying to copy a csv file with foreign key dependence, I get the the error:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

The copy query is like so:

```
\copy table_name FROM '/location_of_csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Is there a way to collect all the failed foreign keys and print them out before postgres throws the error?

Is there a command to ignor rows that violate the constraint?

Comment: Suggest you copy your csv to a temporary table (that has no constraints) from which you just load valid rows to table_name

Comment: @Slumdog this is possible, in fact, I did write a python script to check against invalid foreign keys. I was just wondering if postgres has a faster method or a way to do it with a command